# How to prevent that page 'jumps to the top' in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not a jQuery expert, but tried to create a (simple) function where users can simple click on a button to upvote an item. After a lot of failures, I managed to create the following:

**jQuery**

```
    function vote(_obj) {    
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            data: "id=" + $(_obj).attr("id"), 
            url: "vote.php"
        });  
    }

    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        vote(this);
    });
```

So every time a user click, the page refresh (and automatically jumps to the top of the page). I tried already do add a e.preventDefault(); but without any results.

**HTML/CSS**

```
<a href="" id="a8d186542e782684c0b43b36b994e3eb" class="favorite"><i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i></a>
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the default action of the click. This would prevent a form submitting or a link from following it's href url or whatever the default of that element is when that event occurs

```
$('.favorite').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    vote(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prevent reloading

You can use preventDefault() function like this to prevent your browser from reloading :

In your Javascript :

```
$('.favorite').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    vote(this);
});
```

Your `a` tag doesn't have `href` value so it looks like reloading page (but it's browsing to the same page).

## Update vote value

To update your vote value, you can use `success()` function of jQuery's Ajax call, and update value as you want (ex: only increase or getting value from the call's response), using selector to update the right value.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    data: "id=" + $(_obj).attr("id"), 
    url: "vote.php",
    success : function(response){
        // update your value here, using selector
        // ex: $('.vote-' + $(_obj).attr('id')).val(response.vote)
    },
    error: function(response) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks micster, I forgot to say that I have a counter next to the icon. Now the page doesn't refresh (but the function in triggered), so that is the first step. Is there a way that only the counter refresh?

Comment: @GlennS you might like to ask a new question as this is substantially different from the original question.

Comment: It's a new question but I updated my answer with the vote's value updating part

Answer (score 0):

In additional to `e.preventDefault()` you can use `return false;` from a jquery event handler.

```
$('.favorite').click(function() {
    vote(this);
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, semantically this *should really be a `<button>`* not an `<a>`, make it `type='button'` and it won't do anything other than your code (the default is `type=submit` so needs the `type=` specified otherwise will attempt to submit your form).  You may need to add some css to stop it looking like a "button".

```
<button type='button' class="favorite">
    <i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i>
</button>
```

with your same existing code